# Read until end of line

Tags: mysql, c, parsing, scanf

I have a file that has over 6,000 lines of error data.

```
P000800 Engine Position System Performance
P000900 Engine Position System Performance
P001000 "A" Camshaft Position Actuator Circuit
P001100 "A" Camshaft Position - Timing Over-Advanced or System Performance
P001200 "A" Camshaft Position - Timing Over-Retarded
```

The first string is always at the left and then space and the description.

For the life of me I can't seem to remember how to get it to read the description until
end of line.

I'm putting this into another file that will look like this for MySQL import

```
P000800,Engine Position System Performance
P000900,Engine Position System Performance
P001000,"A" Camshaft Position Actuator Circuit
P001100,"A" Camshaft Position - Timing Over-Advanced or System Performance
P001200,"A" Camshaft Position - Timing Over-Retarded
```

Unless you know of an easier way to make it compatible for MySQL database.

```
while ( (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp_code) != NULL) && (line[0] != '\n') ){
    sscanf(line,"%s %s",ercode, desc);
}
```

Thanks
Bob

Comment: Some ideas at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31095/reading-unlimited-input-strings-in-c/31106#31106

Comment: `if (sscanf(line,"%s %[^\n]",ercode, desc) ==2) GoodToGo();`

Answer (score 0):

How did you declare `line`: is it something like `char *line` or `char line[100]`? It matters because the way you get its size is using the `sizeof` operator. For the first one, `sizeof` will give you the size of a pointer, whereas for the second one, it will give you the real size which is 100.

Also your check of newline character should be the last character, `line[strlen(line) - 1]`, and not the first character, `line[0]`.

Another thing, you cannot rely on `fgets` getting all the characters in the line because you are limited by the `sizeof(line)`. One solution is to iterate until you get the newline character, and then process the string as a whole.

Comment: I declared it char line[256];

Comment: chux & R Sahu these worked great. They are not allowing me to up vote your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Actual implementation I've seen, which is not so elegant but worked, was to make `sscanf` scan the certain number of `%s`'s like this:

```
// scans up to 50 words in a line
int Read_Words_From_String(char *StringLine, char **StringArray)
{
    return(sscanf(StringLine, "%s%s..//which goes on to the count of 50..%s%s", 
                  StringArray[0], // would contain ercode in your case
                  StringArray[1], 
                    :  // which goes on to the count of 50
                  StringArray[49]));
}
```

`sscanf` returns the number of words scanned so it can be used as a loop counter to process them into another format of string.

Comment: Why_Do_You_Write_Your_Subroutines_Like_This?

Comment: Oh_Okay. That_Makes_Sense_Now

Comment: I got rid of underbars in the function parameters for posting this answer because they were making horizon scrollbar appear but left the function name intact :)

Comment: though it does beg the question, Why_DID_You_Write_Your_Function_Names_Like_This? (glad to hear you don't anymore).

Comment: @WhozCraig I am glad to hear that you are glad. Anyway it is (or was) not my coding style for over 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that should work for lines that are almost as long as `BUFSIZ`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   char token[10];
   char rest[BUFSIZ];

   FILE* in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   if ( in == NULL )
   {
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   // Explanation of the format:
   // %9s     Read at most 9 characters into a string
   // %[^\n]  Read all characters until '\n' into a string
   // %*c     Read a character but don't store it. Takes care of
   //         getting rid of the `\n' from the input stream.
   while ( fscanf(in, "%9s %[^\n]%*c", token, rest) == 2 )
   {
      printf("%s,%s\n", token, rest);
   }

   fclose(in);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```